# How can I force a NSDateFormatter to be used as 12 hours or 24 hours format?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, nsdateformatter, swift2

My iOS app will format the time from a timestamp to a time string.
I would like to provide a setting in the app which will override the 12/24 hours format of the system.

What I tried:

```
 self.timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle;
 let locale:NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale();
 if(Constants.isFormat12()){
     timeFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("hh:mm", options: 0, locale: locale);
 }else{
     timeFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm", options: 0, locale: locale);
 }
```

This code will work if the system is under 12 hours format, but not 24 hours format.

I read some post on stackoverflow, they suggest to set the locale of the `NSDateFormatter` to `en_US_POSIX` and `en_GB` so that the time will format in 12 or 24 hours format.

```
    if(Constants.isFormat12()){
        timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX");
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a";
    }else{
        timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB");
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm";
    }
```

However, the 12 hours format will show `AM` and `PM`, instead of the localised version of "AM" and "PM" in different language, such as "上午" & "下午" in Chinese.

Will there be any way to force NSDateFormatter to use 12/24 hours?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you should have an app setting for this. Let the user choose the setting that they prefer for their device in settings, and then use `timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle` (no `locale` override; no `dateFormat` override) and be done with it. I don't want to live in a world where I'm managing 12 vs 24 hour clock settings in each app I use.

Comment: @Rob What if I will follow what the 12/24 hours setting when the app very first launch, but allowing them to choose afterwards? ;)

Comment: Hey, do whatever you want, but it seems like a confusing situation where the user no longer knows where they should be changing their clock localization preferences. What if they've run the app, and later change the value in Settings. What then? Providing a user two different places to specify the 12/24 hour clock settings can only be a source of confusion, IMHO. I'd advise against app-specific 12/24 hour clock setting unless there's something unique to your app where you reasonably expect a user to say, for example, "I want 24 hour clock everywhere except in this one app" (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

what is the trouble?

```
import Foundation

let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hh.mm")
let time = NSDate()           // "17 Nov 2015 14:42"
formater.stringFromDate(time) // "2:42 PM"
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm")
formater.stringFromDate(time) // "14:42"
```

.. Chinese

```
import Foundation

let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hh.mm")
let time = NSDate()           // "17 Nov 2015 15:05"
formater.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh_CN")
formater.stringFromDate(time) // "3:04 下午"
formater.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm")
formater.stringFromDate(time) // "15:05"
```